# Spotfire cross table - calculate difference when multiple hierarchies are on Columns

Tags: tibco, spotfire

I am trying to create a custom expression in Spotfire to calculate the difference between time periods in a cross table which has **multiple hierarchies on the columns** (for example, one is a product hierarchy and the other is the time hierarchy). All the examples I have seen seem to work only if the time hierarchy is the single property selected on an axis.

My scenario is that I want to show in a cross table the sum of sales per category or products (selected through a product hierarchy slider on the columns axis) across different time periods (selected through a time hierarchy also on the column axis), together with the difference from the previous period f**or the same category or product**. The rows axis is set to the customer name.

The default expression Spotfire suggests for "Difference" actually shows the difference relative to the previous "cell" in the cross table, **regardless if it is for the same product/category or not**. In the example screenshot [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B37f9j5HIS4VckFSTTBDcFF4M2s/view?usp=sharing), the difference for Product A for 2014 is shown as "13" even though there is no previous time period for product A. The value of "13" is actually the difference between the sales for product A for 2014 and the sales for product B in 2014 from another category, which happens to be the previous value on the same row.

The example analysis can be found at [here](https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B37f9j5HIS4Vb1kyVzM4LUdvcW8).

I would much appreciate some hints on how I can get the difference to the previous time period for the same product and/or category (depending on what the user selected in the product hierarchy slider).

Comment: What version of Spotfire are you on? 7.0? I'm on 6.5 and got an error trying to open the dxp. `Error message: Unable to read the file DiffWithMultipleHierarchies.dxp. This version of TIBCO Spotfire cannot read files of version 2.2 Cloud.` Good question though and +1 for screenshot and an example analysis.

Comment: @clesiemo3 cloud and on premise are not compatible. the cloud version is normally a couple of revisions ahead and the format isn't forwards-compatible. you might be able to hack around this (dxp is an archive - rename to .zip and explore!) but it's unlikely :(

Comment: @clesiemo3 The example was built using a trial Spotfire Cloud account. They have a free 30-day trial period, you can get one here: https://spotfire.cloud.tibco.com/tsc/?_ga=1.30315071.1436221724.1434016531#!/tryworkgroup without any hassle. You can then easily upload the dxp to the Web Player using the New Analysis option, or, once logged, download the desktop client from [https://spotfire.cloud.tibco.com/tsc/#!/downloads](https://spotfire.cloud.tibco.com/tsc/#!/downloads)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to build an expression to calculate properly the difference I wanted to have. The expression is:

```
Sum([Amount]) - Sum([Amount]) OVER (Intersect(PreviousPeriod([Axis.Columns]),[Hierarchy.ProductHierarchy]))
```

Basically, this is intersecting the previous period on the columns with the non-time hierarchy, which seems to yield the proper result.